# ¿Como puedo solucionar el error Spawn Eperm en ionic v3 para una app iOS?

Tags: ionic, ios

Me encuentro realizando una app para iOS con ionic, esta se construía perfectamente, realice un cambio minimo del código y aparecio este error al momento de construir nuevamente la app:

```
ionic cordova build ios --verbose   ionic:lib Terminal info: { tty: true, ci: false, windows: false } +0ms   ionic:lib CLI global options: { _: [ 'cordova', 'build', 'ios' ], help: null, h: null, verbose: true, quiet: null, interactive: true, color: true, confirm: null, json: null, project: null, '--': [] } +4ms   ionic:lib:project Project type from config: Ionic 2/3 (ionic-angular) +0ms   ionic:lib:project Project details: { configPath: '/Users/redpsi/Desktop/redpsi_inbox_test/ionic.config.json', errors: [], context: 'app', type: 'ionic-angular' } +0ms   ionic Context: { binPath: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/bin/ionic', libPath: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic', execPath: '/Users/redpsi/Desktop/redpsi_inbox_test', version: '4.10.2' } +0ms   ionic:lib:integrations:cordova:config Using config.xml: /Users/redpsi/Desktop/redpsi_inbox_test/config.xml +0ms   ionic:lib:telemetry Sending telemetry for command: 'ionic cordova build' [ 'ios', '--verbose', '--interactive', '--color' ] +0ms   ionic:lib:hooks Looking for ionic:build:before npm script. +0ms   ionic:lib:project:ionic-angular:build Looking for ionic:build npm script. +0ms
> ionic-app-scripts build --target cordova --platform ios Error: spawn EPERM

    at ChildProcess.spawn (internal/child_process.js:358:11)
    at Object.spawn (child_process.js:538:9)
    at spawn  (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/cross-spawn/index.js:12:24)
    at spawn  (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/@ionic/cli-framework/utils/shell.js:136:12)
    at ShellCommand.spawn  (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/@ionic/cli-framework/utils/shell.js:125:16)
    at ShellCommand.run  (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/@ionic/cli-framework/utils/shell.js:87:24)
    at Shell.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/lib/shell.js:34:37)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled  (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:104:62) 

ionic Error: spawn EPERM   ionic     

at ChildProcess.spawn (internal/child_process.js:358:11)   ionic     
at Object.spawn (child_process.js:538:9)   ionic     
at spawn (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/cross-spawn/index.js:12:24) ionic     
at spawn (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/@ionic/cli-framework/utils/shell.js:136:12) ionic     
at ShellCommand.spawn (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/@ionic/cli-framework/utils/shell.js:125:16) ionic     
at ShellCommand.run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/@ionic/cli-framework/utils/shell.js:87:24)   ionic     
at Shell.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/lib/shell.js:34:37)   ionic     at Generator.next (<anonymous>)   ionic     
at fulfilled (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:104:62)
+133ms
```

trate de devolver los cambios sin embargo sigue apareciendo

Answer (score -1):

Tuve el mismo problema, hice lo siguiente y ya pude construirlo:

1. `ionic cordova platform rm android`
2. `ionic cordova platform add android`
3. `delete folder node_modules`
4. `npm install`

Comment: El formato de `código` puede servir para entender mejor lo que se está leyendo, ejemplo, la letra ele pasa a `l`, lo cual aclara que es una ele y no una i mayúscula (`I`). Dicho esto, no entiendo por qué se ha rechazado la edición sugerida que dieron.